# PostgreSQL IP inet comparison using django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In my PostgreSQL database, I have a table of network devices.

I am building a django app that has to interact with this table. I am using models with .get() and .filter() methods, but I am not sure how to deal with the following query:

```
select * from my_table where ip << inet '10.93.1/24'
```

This should get records like `10.93.1.*`, but not `10.93.13.*`, so I can't just use:

```
items = MyTable.objects.filter(ip__startswith='10.93.1')
```

What is the django equivalent for this query?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Yes, see below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution: instead of `filter`, I'm using another `QuerySet` method - [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

So, here's my code now:

```
objList = MyTable.objects.extra(where=["ip << inet '{}'".format(ip)])
```

Note: `where` argument of `extra` method expects a list. It then treats each element of the list as a condition, and combines them with `AND`. So, passing just a string:

```
objList = MyTable.objects.extra(where="ip << inet '{}'".format(ip))
```

would cause `extra` to treat this string as a list of characters, which would result in a query:

```
...WHERE (i) AND (p) AND ( ) AND (<) AND (<) AND ( ) AND (i) AND (n) AND (e) AND (t) AND ( ) AND (') AND (1) AND (0) AND (.) AND (9) AND (3) AND (.) AND (1) AND (/) AND (2) AND (4) AND (')
```

Comment: Good solution (even though `extra` is in line for deprecation and carries a long list of warnings in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks! I saw the warnings, but I like the simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default lookup for that (as of v2.2), but it's easy to [create one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-lookups/):

```
from django.db.models import GenericIPAddressField
from django.db.models import Lookup

@GenericIPAddressField.register_lookup
class ContainedIn(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'iscontainedin'

    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s << inet %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

Then you can use the lookup with `__iscontainedin`:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(ip__iscontainedin='10.93.1/24')
```

---

Too bad about boilerplate involved in creating a lookup. If you're only using this once, an `extra` query is indeed less trouble. For repeated use, an appropriately named lookup will be more readable and less code to maintain.